# NPM Version is not Downgrading

Tags: node.js, npm

Node Version : `14.16.1`
NPM Version  : `7.12.0`

I'm trying to downgrade the NPM version to `6.14.13` without downgrading Node for some reasons. But the following commands are not working for me.

```
npm install -g npm@6
npm install -g npm@6.14.13
```

I tried them several times but still NPM version is showing `7.12.0`. Don't have idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to install `NVM`.

I am not sure but you could try this
Run your terminal as admin (in case there are permission issues as I had). Then use a specific node version (say 7.8.0) by

```
nvm use 7.8.0
```

then update your npm to desired specific version by

```
npm install -g npm@6.14.13
```

and get back to `nvm install --lts`